# Customize HP Laptop Recovery Image

Tags: recovery-console

Is there any way to customize the image that loads when I do a system recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Storage/Backup_Restore/Q_22987736.html) discusses what you're looking to do.. It is something you could theoretically do from scratch and replace the HP image, but not modify the HP provided restore image. It would take an array of programs, many of which aren't free, to even attempt the process, but it looks like it could be done.